# Trying to understand Android setText in onCreate of Activity with Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, oncreate, settext

If I try to setText on a TextView in the onCreate() of an Activity, I always get a "Unfortunately, XXX has stopped." message.

I had previously avoided this being a necessity by doing any setText code in onStart(). At first I thought this was because you shouldn't setText a UI item in the onCreate() as it was not yet visible, but I don't think so now.

I think I now need to do setText in onCreate() as I want to use the savedInstanceState Bundle for screen orientation flipping.

I have the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_hmc);

    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add (R.id.container,new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
    else
    {
        // This line works, I see a Toast and the data from "output" is displayed.
        ShowToast (savedInstanceState.getString ("output"));

        // This line also executes without causing any issue.
        TextView tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView4);
        // This line causes a "Unfortunately, XXX has stopped" error message.
        tvOutput.setText (savedInstanceState.getString ("output"));
    }
}
```

I was wondering if it is because I am using the Fragment created by Android Studio to hold my UI components. If so, do I need to place this test retrieval and setText code in the following method?

```
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_hmc,container,false);

        return rootView;
    }
```

I see many other samples of code where people are using setText on UI components in the onCreate method of the Activity... most problems with this not working appear to be related to not using setContentView or not using findViewById before calling setText - but you can see I am doing both of those, hopefully correctly.

So - if I am using a Fragment to hold my UI components, does this mean I cannot use setText on those UI components in the Activity's onCreate() method?

Many thanks for helping me understand this better... once taught I'll remember forever.

Comment: Post your logcat. `tvOutput` is probably null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize your TextView in onCreateView, and with rootView. So, your code should look like this:

```
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_hmc,container,false);

    TextView tvOutput = (TextView) rootView.findViewById (R.id.textView4);
    tvOutput.setText (savedInstanceState.getString ("output"));

    return rootView;
}
```

And remove your initialization from MainActivity ;)

Comment: Thanks. When I move code into `onCreateView` - the `savedInstanceState.getString ("output")` doesn't return the data I know has been placed in there in the `onSaveInstanceState` method. I can see that data in the Activity's `onCreate()` method, but not in the `onCreateView()` method - aren't they supposed to be the same `Bundle savedInstanceState`?

Comment: I think the fragment has it's own savedInstanceState and the activity too. So, when you want to save and retreive the instance state of the Activity, keep the getString("output"); command in the onCreate of the Activity. But when you are going to need your "output" String in your fragment, save and retreive savedInsatnceState in your fragment only ;) And sorry for my english :D

Comment: I thought they would be the same `savedInstanceState`. So, I need to do the following then... 1) save my data in `onSaveInstanceState` method. 2) read that data back into `Strings` in the Activity's `onCreate()` method and save them, 3) do `setText` on UI components in the Fragment's `onCreateView` method? P.S. - I can confirm that `setText` with a literal 'String` "hello" works in the Fragment's `onCreateView` method... this is just a little more onerous than I had expected.

Comment: You can just store it in the fragment's saved instance state ;) it's much easier ;)

Comment: Thank you, this works. I didn't have access to a `View` in the Fragment's `onSaveInstanceState` method, so I made a `View mRootView` variable in the class that I created in `onCreateView` and then I could access that in `onSaveInstanceState` for getting access to my `TextView` and its `setText` method. So I am saving the state of things in the Fragment and retrieving them in the Fragment. Confirmed that this all works.

Comment: My default Fragment setup was 10.1" WXGA (Tablet) and I'd set all UI items up in landscape. I decided to use Android Studio's wizard to create another XML file in `res/layout-port` and it's done that. I then moved UI bits around on the layout for portrait view. When I flip the tablet screen I do see the different layout (which is good) but my `savedInstanceState` isn't returning data in the Fragment's `onCreateView`. I'm surprised anything has changed because it's still the same Fragment, with a layout defined by an XML file of the same name, just in `res/layout-port` instead of `res/layout`.

Comment: Something similar happens to me too, that's why I don't have rotation allowed in my app :P

Comment: OK, at app startup, the `TextView` I want to save has a Text value of resource `@string/lReady`. As the program runs, this `TextView` has text added to it via `.setText` and `.append`. Rotation works fine if the program has been used, but if it's just been initialised then I get an "Unfortunately, XXX has stopped" message. So in `onStart` I added a line of fixup code to set the `TextView` to "Ready..."; this avoided the error, but was resetting the `TextView` to "Ready..." making it **appear** as if the saving and restoring of data wasn't working. I now and use a `catch` later on.